# Multi-variate hotspot mapping in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation, hot-spot

I'm looking to create a map similar to the one below--essentially an interpolated map, but using multiple *categorical* variables. Has anyone seen an application of interpolation that can do this in ArcGIS? I was able to find an article from the author, but the closest [reference](https://news.ncsu.edu/2013/06/you-say-tomato-i-say-soda-or-is-it-pop/) to the method was:

> Katz created a statistical algorithm that weighted the responses around a particular location. The approach let Katz create colorful maps that show how regional dialects are spread across the country.

[image]

I attempted to recreate something like this with basic hotpsot symbology and overlaid transparency but it had a few downsides-- no single dataset for analysis, cannot be clipped, and the weight of each category was heavily influenced by the ordering of the layer.

[image]

Comment: How would you intend to store the purely categorical data so that you know where it merges or how strong the color should be? My understanding of the data behind the map you posted is that it is storing what percentage of the population uses a given term. So something like four attribute columns, each with a 0-1 value for any given spatial unit. Or in raster format, one layer per term with pixel values of 0-1.

Comment: The "strength" of the color would be related to point density with each collection point being given a value of one. Converting to numerical symbology is easy, its the interpolation bit between the data values that gets me. In the example above, moving from a high Soda population to a high Pop population has a gradient. But adding an additional variable to that gradient is... challenging.

Comment: You could also reach out and ask the author about the specific methods he used to make the map. He's got enough of a web presence I'm sure you can find some sort of contact info in there somewhere. I also found another article which goes into a lot more of the data science behind his work. Not sure it would be helpful in figuring out the cartography too. https://towardsdatascience.com/the-data-science-behind-the-new-york-times-dialect-quiz-part-1-4935ff06069a

Comment: Please keep in mind that the analysis you are referencing used a kNN algorythm, which is not available in ArcGIS/Pro.  I would contact the author for specifics on the methodology and not just assume a hot-spot analysis.